# JsonObjectRequest doesn't response neither listener or errorListener

Tags: android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

My JsonObjectRequest doesn't do as my instructions.
Does volley API go on strike?
My log cat just says "Requested URL: http://..".
My log cat doesn't say neither "Json Parsing Error:" or "HTTP Request Error:".
Please, anybody, tell me What did I do wrong.

```
String url = REST_URL + "?seq=" + mLastSeq;
Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Requested URL: "+url);
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    mLastSeq = response.getInt("last");
                    mNewCount = response.getInt("count");
                    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, mLastSeq+"");
                    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, mNewCount+"");
                    if (mNewCount>0) {
                        String title = mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                        String message = mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.new_news_alert);
                        showNotification(title, message);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException error) {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Json Parsing Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "HTTP Request Error:" + error.getMessage());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.